# Setup an Email server

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I know that the title of this post is not very indicative. But I thought the simpler it was the more people would watch.

I am trying to set up a mail server with Ubuntu 20.04. The software I am using are: Dovecot, Postfix and Fetchmail. The machine where I work is running webmin which allows me to access the server management directly from the browser. Returning to the main problem, I would like to ask you if anyone has any advice for configuring the 3 software. Should I first configure Postfix, then Dovecot and finally fatchmail or is it better to start from something else?

Comment: If your goal is to set up a generic mail server using Ubuntu, then I would recommend following one of the **multiple** guides there exist on the Internet. I personally used a guide from Howtoforge which also installed ISPConfig for easier manegement of mail accounts vs console commands, but that is just my preference. You problably have other preferences. In any case I don't think your question is a good fit for ServerFault as it is more a help to get unstuck when you run into a problem during install rather than a step-by-step guide in how to install.

Comment: Since setting up a server these days is a lot of work I would recommend against it.
If you decide to continue, please remember that you need to have a static IP, be able to set the PTR DNS records correctly. Things to read up on is also SPF and DKIM. And please make sure that noone can abuse your server by sending spam. Some verification can be done with MXToolbox.

Comment: If you want to learn how to configure a mail server, DO IT!! Don't let the haters distract you from achieving your goal. However, this question is still off-topic for Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could get inspiration from that: [Mail-in-a-Box](https://github.com/mail-in-a-box/mailinabox)